# Flutter : Could not get unknown property 'keystoreProperties' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, flutter-web

Everytime I try to build my app bundle it shows me this error.

`Could not get unknown property 'keystoreProperties' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

I have tried multiple solutions but none of them works

ref1 : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28132

ref2 : [Flutter Android Studio Error: couldn't get unknown property 'keystoreProperty'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607817/flutter-android-studio-error-couldnt-get-unknown-property-keystoreproperty)

ref3 : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#generated-project-files-outdated

this is my `build.gradle` file,

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
android {
    // compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.bot_write"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

this is my key.properties file

```
keyAlias=upload
keyPassword=password
storeFile=d:/keystores/notesapp/upload-keystore.jks
storePassword=storepass
```

I have tried other stack overflow answers but none of them works.
some solutions I have tried

1. changing folder from d: to c:
2. changing forward slash for path

```
storeFile=d:\keystores\botwrite\upload-keystore.jks
storeFile=c:\Users\upload-keystore.jks
storeFile=d:/keystores/notesapp/upload-keystore.jks
```

3. running `flutter packages pub cache repair`
4. running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`
5. running `flutter build appbundle`

my android folder
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your storepassword is right?

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid yes my storepassword is right.

Comment: Where you put key.proppertyfile?

Comment: Means direct into a android folder or any sub folder?

Comment: I've put it in android root folder. right next to `gradle.propertie` and `local.properties`

Comment: that's correct path

Comment: are you able to open project in android studio? only android

Comment: I didn't try that. wait a minute I'll do it right now and tell you.

Comment: Okay which command are you using for generating apk?

Comment: `Project android is using the following JDK location when running Gradle: D:/Installed_softwares/android_studio/jre Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal while using Android Studio.`
could this error be a problem. When I opened this project in android studio it showed me this warning

Comment: Are you getting above error?

Comment: Error or warning ?

Comment: I was getting this warning, and I fixed it.

Comment: Okay now tell me one thing , are you able to run the project from android studio?

Comment: No. I don't know how to directly run an android project.

Comment: Can you please explain the correct way of writing `storefile` path ?

Comment: Actually, i m mac user so i m directly putted on my project location like this : {storeFile=/Users/rahul-variya-us/Documents/loop/loop-app/android/loop-keystore.jks}

Comment: Also you can generete apk from android studio as well

Comment: If you want to show then let me know

Comment: If anyone knows what causes this error, please explain. That way I will be able to address this problem specifically. Thank you for any suggestion. 
thank you @rahulVFlutterAndroid

Comment: Welcome , i have another way to create apk if you want then let me know

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid I'll be grateful. Please join me I'd love to show you. 
google meet link : https://meet.google.com/vrv-pksd-zco

Comment: Right now i m not right place to connect sorry for that

Comment: If you need apk right now then let me know

Comment: i have another option for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251361/discussion-between-rahulvflutterandroid-and-abdulhaseeeb).

Comment: Okay. I'm there.

Comment: If still stuck, please make sure u have correctly mention the keystore file path and added // slashes instead of / slash. check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608768/11044933

Answer (score 2):

Your build.gradle file seems to be missing line:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key. Properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Regards,
Claudio

Comment: I missed the "def keystoreProperties = new Properties()" line as well (thinking that it was in the example just to show where the other 3 lines should go). Pretty obvious really now that I look at it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the apk by opening the project in android studio :

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is a good workaround. But it didn't solve actual problem. 
If anyone else have this same problem do this
(reset your previous setup : i.e. key.properties file and all other related files)
1. If you are using vscode right click on android folder > click "open in android studio"
2. next Click > Build > Generate Signed Bundle / apks
3. next follow these steps : 
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?authuser=2#sign-apk

Comment: I haven't tried this workaround, but the answer from @Claudio Grasso fixed the same problem when I had it.

Comment: Okay @JasonB thanks can u please accept this answer?